# Connect two drop down menu whit Mysqli

Tags: mysqli, drop-down-menu

I have this two drop down menu ,  they get values from Mysqli data base
firs menu for company name second one for project of company
I want when i select company from first menu , just that project appear on second menu of that company i selected

```
    <form id="company" name="company" method="post" action="">
    <label for="company"></label>
    <select name="company" id="company">
    <?php
    $cmpsql="SELECT * FROM company  ";
    $cmpresult=mysqli_query($mng,$cmpsql);
    $row_cmp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cmpresult);
   do {
   ?>  
   <option value="<?php echo $row_cmp['company'] ?>"><?php echo $row_cmp['company'] ?></option>
  <?php } while ($row_cmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($cmpresult))?>  
  </select>
  <label for="project"></label>
  <select name="project" id="project">
  <?php
  $psql="SELECT * FROM project  ";
  $presult=mysqli_query($mng,$psql);
  $row_p=mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult);
  do {
  ?> 
  <option value="<?php echo $row_p['project'] ?>"><?php echo $row_p['project'] ?></option>
  <?php } while ($row_p= mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult)) ?>
  </select>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem
index page

```
<script src="style/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function getid(val){
$.ajax({
type :"POST",
url : "getdata.php",
data :"cid="+val,
success:function(data){
$("#proje").html(data);
}})}
</script>
<form id="company" name="company" method="post" action="">
<label for="company">Company</label>
<select name="company" id="company" onchange="getid(this.value)">
<?php
$cmpsql="SELECT * FROM company  ";
$cmpresult=mysqli_query($mng,$cmpsql);
$row_cmp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cmpresult);
do {
?>  
<option value="<?php echo $row_cmp['company'] ?>"><?php echo $row_cmp['company'] ?></option>
<?php } while ($row_cmp= mysqli_fetch_assoc($cmpresult))?>  
</select>
<label for="project">Project</label>
<select   name="project" id="proje">
<option value="">Choose Company First</option>
</select>
</form>
```

getdata.php page

```
 <?php require_once('Connections/mng.php');
mysqli_select_db($mng, "management") or die("cannot select DB"); 
$cid=$_POST['cid'];
$psql="SELECT * FROM project WHERE company='$cid' ";
$presult=mysqli_query($mng,$psql);
$row_p=mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult);
do {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_p['project'] ?>"><?php echo $row_p['project'] ?></option>
<?php } while ($row_p= mysqli_fetch_assoc($presult)) ?>
```